# click function not working in the html file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to send the email from the image click in html file but it does not work in the file same thing I am doing in separate file with single image then it is working.
This is where I am calling the code in html

```
    <div class="root_panel_img"><img src="images/main_button.png" id="commandEmail1" /></div>
```

http://codepad.org/jFrQTVrM

Here is the javascript file

http://codepad.org/aagrAjNs

Comment: are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#commandEmail1").click(function() {
            ......
            ......

            "You can test this if it is working or not by putting an alert("OK") message."
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

So according to code provided the following isn't working?

```
$("#commandEmail2").click(function() {
    presenter.command("emailSend",{
        "toEmail": "debug@orchard.net.au",
        "toName": "Debug",
        "subject": "Presenter Library Test",
        "body": "Dual Attachment",
        "bodyHtml": "<h1>Dual Attachment</h1>",
        "attachments": ["/pdf/ip6.pdf","/pdf/docs.pdf"]
    }, status);
    return false;
});
```

does this work?

```
$("#commandEmail2").click(function() {
    alert("this works");
    return false;
});
```

If so then something in presenter.command fails and that is code you haven't posted.